# Thread and Context issue

Tags: android, multithreading, android-context

I'm trying to upload the contacts on a different Thread, I'm getting the application context but it seems not to work. Why?

Here's the code:

```
private void uploadall() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            Contacts contacts = new Contacts(getApplicationContext());
            contacts.phoneandname();

            // Apps
            ListApps mList = new ListApps();
            mList.loadInstalledApps(false, getApplicationContext());

        }
    });
}
```

And when I try to upload without the thread it works perfectly... Why?

Comment: @AndroSelva I'm creating logs in the contacts class, and when i try tu upload without threads it upload all the contacts and shows the log.i(); but when i put a thread then doesn't do anything.

Comment: you do not start() the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually starting the thread, try the following:

```
private void uploadall() {
  Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      ...
    }
  });

  thread.start();
}
```

The Oracle concurrency tutorial is quite a good resource when starting out with multi-threading in Java and can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html).

Answer (score 1):

try as:

```
private void uploadall() {
private Context context=getApplicationContext();

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

            Contacts contacts = new Contacts(context);
            contacts.phoneandname();

            // Apps
            ListApps mList = new ListApps();
            mList.loadInstalledApps(false,context);

        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

Comment: Oh...sheet... it's my fault! Thanks!